# https connection from controller.js in ionic app

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, ionic-framework

i am new to angularjs and ionic development. In my app, i am using $http in controller to send a GET message. But now i need to send GET request to a https URL, it always give me error code *403*.

```
$scope.caption1 = "Empty";
$scope.method = 'GET';
$scope.url = 'index.html'; 
$http({method: $scope.method, url: $scope.url}).
        then(function(response) {
        console.log('Request successful');
        if (response.data.reported.status === 'Vacant') {
        $scope.caption1 = "Empty";
        }else{
        $scope.caption1 = "Filled";
        }
          $scope.data = response.data;
        }, function(response) {
        console.log('Request failed');
         $scope.caption1 = "Error in connection";
          });
    };
```

**My https URL is of AWS http api, it requires certificate to be attached**

Comment: did you add the URL to the whitelist in your config.xml file? \n
`<access origin="https://whatever.com"/>`
for example i have google set like this `<access origin="https://maps.google.com"/>` and `<allow-navigation href="https://maps.google.com"/>`

Comment: how will i attach certificate